# How many billionaires have run for the office of the US president thus far?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

How many billionaires ran for the office of the US president thus far?

Was there any other guy other than Trump and Ross Perot?

Comment: Can you cite any data showing Trump is a billionaire? :)

Comment: @blip, https://www.google.com/search?q=donald+trump+net+worth&oq=donald+trump+net+worth&aqs=chrome..69i57.4938j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @blip, https://www.forbes.com/donald-trump/#3938d7b42899

Comment: ..one too many?

Comment: It took me all of 1 minute to find an answer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States_by_net_worth and http://content.time.com/time/interactive/0,31813,2106519,00.html

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, irrelevant. Read the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other **billionaire** has run for president (although most presidential candidates tend to be multi-millionaire). It is however worth noting that [J.F.K family estates](http://content.time.com/time/interactive/0,31813,2106519,00.html) were worth about a $1 billion.

Comment: The rough estimate of FDR's $60M wealth in 1932 translates to $992M in 2017 dollars...... so close.....